# How to retrieve values from database

Tags: php, android, database, android-maps

I have written a android program to store user location info (lat and lon values) to database. This works fine.

What i need to do is "to retrieve those latitude and longitude values from database and mark a route on map". The following is my part of code which draws map according to the given latitude and longitude values. I found this part of code by surfing net. I dont know how to make it accept data from DB and mark it on map. Please give me idea to do that.

```
 function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.524220910029783,73.85761860000002);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
```

Here lat and lon values are given directly. I need to retrieve those values from DB instead of giving it directly.

Following is my PHP code to store location information got from android app in to DB

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="map"; // Table name 
$message=$_POST['a'];
$message1=$_POST['b'];
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$query = "INSERT INTO map (id,longitude,latitude) VALUES (DEFAULT,'".$_REQUEST['message']."', '".$_REQUEST['message1']."')";


mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error("error"));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: so you want to retrieve from web and that lat ,lon should be use in native code is it?

Comment: yes..i dont want to give the lat lon value directly inside my js code. I just want to retrieve it from database. I am using MySQL DB

Comment: I am trying to do it in web

Comment: Is there any tutorial for that.. I am new to this field..

Comment: please change your user name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) will show you how to fetch data from db.This is php task.